# Matrix, Synapse server can't be reached

Tags: docker, docker-compose, matrix

I set up a matrix server and everything seems to be happy, but I can't connect to the server.
Calling it with: `matrix.myDomain.de` results in `ERR_TIMED_OUT`

Calling it with: `matrix.myDomain.de:8008` results in `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I get an answer when I ping `matrix.myDomain.de` from command line.

My guess is, that I'm missing a config that exposes the service to the internet.

### This is what I did:

1. Setup Domain, SSL(let's encrypt), DNS entry
2. Setup folder structure (content in data/ is created by docker compose)

   matrix

   ├── bridges

   ├── data

   │   ├── homeserver.db

   │   ├── homeserver.db-shm

   │   ├── homeserver.db-wal

   │   ├── homeserver.yaml

   │   ├── matrix.myDomain.de.log.config

   │   ├── matrix.myDomain.de.signing.key

   │   └── media_store

   └── docker-compose.yml
3. docker-compose run --rm synapse generate

- There I got the error message:

  Network server declared as external, but could not be found. Please create the network manually using `docker network create server` and try again.

4. docker network create server
5. docker-compose run --rm synapse generate
6. docker-compose up -d

### State of the setup:

docker ps

```
5a008b8f901e   matrixdotorg/synapse:latest   "/start.py"              27 minutes ago   Up 27 minutes (healthy)   8009/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8008->8008/tcp, :::8008->8008/tcp, 8448/tcp                                                                             synapse
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
 synapse:
  image: "matrixdotorg/synapse:latest"
  container_name: "synapse"
  volumes:
   - "./data:/data"
  ports:
   - "8008:8008"
  environment:
   VIRTUAL_HOST: "matrix.myDomain.de"
   VIRTUAL_PORT: 8008
   LETSENCRYPT_HOST: "matrix.myDomain.de"
   SYNAPSE_SERVER_NAME: "matrix.myDomain.de"
   SYNAPSE_REPORT_STATS: "yes"
  networks: ["server"]

networks:
 server:
  external: true
```

docker network ls

```
b080029e1fab   server    bridge    local
```

My question:

Am I missing something, do I need to connect the docker bridge to the container? My understanding is, that already is happening with the `networks` point in the .yml file.

I'm currently lost and couldn't find any helpful guide.

Comment: A timeout usually indicates a firewall issue.

Comment: Additionally, there is nothing in the information you provided that anything is listening on the default ports 80 or 443.

Comment: That's correct, there is no web server running. I picked up that some people are running reverse proxies with nginx, but I thought that was optional.
If I specify the port 8008 I get a ´ERR_TIMED_OUT´, if not a ´ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED´